# React-final form: Filed checkbox can only one selected?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Hello i have some question

follow this simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ww40y2m595

how to make Field Sauces (checkbox) is only one select like Field Best Stooge(radio) ?

****** Field Sauces still use input type = checkbox ************

ex.i try some way such as use mutators function to changvalue but still not work

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that’s the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can change all the checkboxes with name `sauces` from type `checkbox` to type `radio` if you only want one to be selected.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/34vn6n7py5))**

```
<label>
  <Field name="sauces" component="input" type="radio" value="guacamole" />
  Guacamole 
</label>
```